# LINQPad DbProviderFactories GetFactoryClasses

Tags: linqpad, dbproviderfactories

I have found that adding an entry to the DbProviderFactories in LINQPad.exe.config does not make it show up in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().Dump();

I had to add it to machine.config to be able to see it and use it. Is that to be expected?

Specifically I was trying to add the Oracle ODP managed entry since an assembly I reference requires it. I am told that the point of using the managed provider was to make the assembly more self contained and portable and so having to touch machine.config trashes that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to Linqpad.config. The Linqpad.exe.config file is for LINQPad itself whereas linqpad.config is for your queries.